# jQuery data() and attr() methods, and JavaScript dataset property return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="price" itemprop="price" content="66.00">66.00</span>
```

I am trying to get the value of the `content` data attribute in the span, but I keep getting ***undefined*** instead of the price value.

I've tried using `$(".price").data("content")`, `$(".price").attr("content")`, `$(".price").prop("content")`, and pure JavaScript `document.querySelector('.price').dataset.content`; however all of these return ***undefined***.

The only way I get an actual value is when there is only one product on the page, I add an **Id** to the span and use `document.getElementById('price').getAttribute("content")`.

I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01kqoje7/9/. Within this fiddle, the `attrPrice` variable is the only variable that gives a value, but in my code, even jQuery's attr() gives me undefined.

Why am I getting undefined when I'm trying to access the data attribute of my class?

P.S. I don't have any control over the naming convention of the data attributes.

Comment: data attributes are those prefixed with `data-`. So `data-content` for example

Comment: `$('.price').attr('content')` should work fine if all of the `.price` elements have a `content` attribute and the code is run after the DOM has loaded. But you shouldn't be inventing your own attributes without prefixing them with `data-`.

Comment: I am guessing the OP is trying to select elements in an iframe, which is why he has no control over the elements and why his valid syntax is not returning the results he is expecting.

Comment: @cale_b My code is inside <script> just before </body>. If I'm using jQuery, it's inside $(function(){}), else outside that.

Comment: Please read about [mcve].  You're asking us to guess now, and we don't have the full picture.

Comment: also, is the content attribute set by javascript? if the content value is being assigned by a script, as opposed to being part of the delivered document, you might have a race condition on your hands.

Comment: @cale_b I created a JSFiddle (link is in my post) for people to play around with. The issue most likely lies in the fact that there are badly name data attributes, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can get around that.

Comment: @Sicypher in the JSFiddle you posted the price element does not have any data attributes (because data attributes start with `data-`). But if you change `$(".price").data("content")` to `$(".price").attr("content")` it will work.

Comment: @Minderov Yes, you're right. It works with the data- prefix, however my problem is that I am unable to change the naming convention. I need to be able to get the value the way things are right now.

Comment: So - this doesn't solve your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/Lf3k8tzr/

Comment: @cale_b Unfortunately it doesn't. using `attr()` works in the fiddle, but not on the website I'm working with. Thank you for trying.

Comment: @Sicypher then it's very unlikely we can solve a problem we can't reproduce. Maybe you can give us the website?

Comment: @Minderov one example of this would be on: https://www.ljsmith.com/newel-posts/box-newels/box-newel-accessories/lj-9204-o-box-newel-large-pic-frame-kit. You could just use the console to try to get the `content` attribute's value of the "price" class.

Comment: Your example url does not contain any elements that are both `.price` AND contain the attributes you describe.  You have to provide an example that reflects the attributes you are after for us to troubleshoot this...

Comment: However, to prove the point - if you execute THIS jquery on the page, you'll see in fact it DOES work: `jQuery('[content]').attr('content');` - so show us a `.price` element with `.content`, and we can likely get it...

Comment: @cale_b thank you. I will try your query.

Comment: @cale_b `$('.price[content]').attr('content');` works! Please submit an answer and I will accept it as the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the attribute you are looking for is `content`, it is possible to use a jQuery [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

For example:

```
// will select ALL items with content attribute:  
$('[content]').attr('content');
```

If you know you want ONLY items with a certain class on it, you can combine the class and attribute selectors like so:

```
// will select items with content attribute that have the price class:
$('.price[content]').attr('content');
```

As others have mentioned, using `$('.price').data('content')` requires that the attribute is prefixed with `data-` (such as `data-content="66.00"`), and can't be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `data-content` instead :

```
<span class="price" itemprop="price" data-content="66.00">66.00</span>
```

**NOTE :** `$(".price2").attr("content")` should work if the element is loaded to the DOM so try to make usre that you're executing your code inside the ready function like :

```
$(function() {
     //Your logic here
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  console.log( $(".price").data("content") );
  console.log( $(".price2").attr("content") );
  console.log( document.querySelector('.price').dataset.content );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="price" itemprop="price" data-content="66.00">66.00</span>
<span class="price2" itemprop="price" content="22.00">22.00</span>
```

Comment: Does it explain why he's getting `undefined` when calling `$(".price").attr("content")`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't have any control over the naming convention of the data properties.

Comment: Should work @Minderov ... check my snippet #Sicypher

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes it should, however the author asked why it does _not_ work

Comment: @Minderov perhaps the author was mistaken? or a buggy version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes guys, but we need the feedback of @Sicypher , to make sure if it has a ready function around his code.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - which means that it was too early to post an answer, wasn't it? :) Because this doesn't answer the problem, it just adds some information....